# Response e Request format

Tags: spring-boot, reflexão

Temos um EndPoint em Rest para acesso a dados de um parceiro, também em Rest. (usamos SpringBoot)

O response deles é todo em português. Conforme a política do nosso cliente, todo o nosso código e interface do EndPoint deve ser em inglês.

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

```
// Controller
@GetMapping("/getClinicalRecord")
public Dermatologist getFichaClinica(@RequestHeader(X_SECURITY_TOKEN) final String token) {

    Usuario usuario = getUsuario(token);
    final Dermatologist response = getFichaClinicaApiService().getFichaClinica(usuario);

    return response;
}

// Response
public class Dermatologist {

    @JsonProperty("temCancer")
    private Integer hasCancer;

    @JsonProperty("cancer")
    private String cancer;

    @JsonProperty("fezCirurgia")
    private Integer didSurgery;

    @JsonProperty("temTatuagem")
    private Integer hasTatto;
}
```

No exemplo acima o controller retorna a classe Dermatologist, porém eu preciso que o retorno seja em inglês. Com os nomes das variáveis.
Porém está sendo exibido conforme os valores informados no JsonProperty.

Existe alguma annotation que resolva isso ?

Me sugeriram criar uma classe para realizar o retorno, e copiar a saída do nosso parceiro nesse novo objeto, que ficaria:

```
public class Dermatologist {

    private Integer hasCancer;
    private String cancer;
    private Integer didSurgery;
    private Integer hasTatto;
}
```

Considerando essa abordagem, tem como eu realizar a cópia dos dois objetos usando Reflection ou coisa do gênero? Lembrado que ai é apenas um exemplo. Os objetos de retornos seriam idênticos, mas possuem listas e outros objetos internos.

Grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de algumas formas, inclusive essa que você citou.

### Usando uma nova classe

A primeira opção é criar uma nova classe (uma espécie de *object adapter*) com os mesmos atributos com os nomes desejados. E então utilizar algo semelhante a um *copy constructor* para facilitar o processo de conversão das classes. Exemplo:

```
public static class DermatologistAdapter {

    @JsonProperty("hasCancer")
    private Integer hasCancer;

    @JsonProperty("cancer")
    private String cancer;

    @JsonProperty("didSurgery")
    private Integer didSurgery;

    @JsonProperty("hasTatto")
    private Integer hasTatto;

    public DermatologistAdapter(Dermatologist dermatologist) {
        this.hasCancer = dermatologist.hasCancer();
        this.cancer = dermatologist.cancer();
        this.didSurgery = dermatologist.didSurgery();
        this.hasTatto = dermatologist.hasTatto();
    }
}
```

E no seu *controller*:

```
GetMapping("/getClinicalRecord")
public DermatologistAdapter getFichaClinica(@RequestHeader(X_SECURITY_TOKEN) final String token) {

    Usuario usuario = getUsuario(token);
    final Dermatologist response = getFichaClinicaApiService().getFichaClinica(usuario);

    return new DermatologistAdapter(response);
}
```

### Usando um *Custom JsonSerializer*

Uma segunda opção é criar um `JsonSerializer` para a classe `Dermatologist`, para que o Jackson à utilize ao invés das anotações. Exemplo:

```
public final class DermatologistSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Dermatologist> {

    @Override
    public final void serialize(Dermatologist value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeNumberField("hasCancer", value.hasCancer());
        gen.writeStringField("cancer", value.cancer());
        gen.writeNumberField("didSurgery", value.didSurgery());
        gen.writeNumberField("hasTatto", value.hasTatto());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

E depois registrá-lo dessa forma:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder j2omb = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(Dermatologist.class, new DermatologistSerializer());
    j2omb.modules(module);
    return j2omb;
}
```

Obs: nesse caso o método do seu *Controller* ficaria inalterado.

### Usando *Mix-in Annotations*

Por último, você também poderia utilizar *Mix-in Annotations*. Exemplo:

```
public abstract class DermatologistMixIn {
    @JsonProperty("") Integer hasCancer;
    @JsonProperty("") String cancer;
    @JsonProperty("") Integer didSurgery;
    @JsonProperty("") Integer hasTatto;
}
```

E depois registrá-lo dessa forma:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder j2omb = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    j2omb.mixIn(Dermatologist.class, DermatologistMixIn.class);
    return j2omb;
}
```

Obs: nesse caso o método do seu Controller também ficaria inalterado.

Comment: Fantástico. Valeu Felipão =]